# Kivy Text Input Width not changing

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on a Kivy app and I have a kv file looking like this. (cutdown to only show the necessary portion)

```
<LoginWindow>:
    username:username
    password:password
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                texture: Gradient.vertical(get_color_from_hex("000000"), get_color_from_hex("000080"))
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            padding_x:[50,50]
                
            TextInput:
                multiline:False
                id:username
                hint_text:"Username"
                padding:[20,20,20,20]
                width:1
        
            TextInput:
                multiline:False
                id:password
                password:True
                hint_text:"Password"
                padding_x:20
```

However when I change the width of the input my kivy file still looks like[image]

In summary the width isn't changing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
TextInput:
    multiline:False
    id:username
    hint_text:"Username"
    padding:[20,20,20,20]
    size_hint: None, None
    width:1
```

This is the only way that I know off that might help with your problem